# Current Date time in a particular format Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am a beginner in python and I have a function where I need to display the current date, time, month, year in the format, something similar to this.

```
Mon Jun 22 14:00:03 UTC 2020
```

I saw pre-defined datetime class but I am not sure how to utilize this class to derive the current date in this format (UTC).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datetime with strftime to get the desired result. You can do it as -

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y")
print(date)
```

**Output :**

```
Mon Jul 06 19:11:33 UTC 2020
```

Basically the syntax is - `datetime.strftime(format)` which will return a string representing date and time using date, time or datetime object. There are many format codes like `%Y`, `%d`, `%m`, etc which you can use to specify the format you want your result to be.

You can read more about them [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
now = datetime.now(tz = timezone.utc)
print(now.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'))
```

Output

```
Mon Jul 06 19:17:58 UTC 2020
```

Comment: this should be the preferred solution; utcnow is [kind of missleading](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html)...

Answer (score 2):

You can use an **f-string**.

Building on [@Balaji Ambresh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12611409/balaji-ambresh) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62762984/4518341):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
now = datetime.now(tz = timezone.utc)
print(f'{now:%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y}')
```

Output

```
Mon Jul 06 19:17:58 UTC 2020
```